# Postgresql cannot archive WAL, after reach above max_wal_size

Tags: postgresql, wal

I have deployed PostgreSQL(v13) using `crunchydata` k8s operator.

currently I found `max_wal_size` is `1GB` using:

```sql
DB=# show max_wal_size;
 max_wal_size 
--------------
 1GB
(1 row)
```

But the current `/pgdata/pg13_wal` size is `4.9Gi`. Why PostgreSQL cannot archive `wal` and reduce `wal` size.

Logs

```
Backup start location: 0/0
Backup end location: 0/0
End-of-backup record required: no
wal_level setting: logical
wal_log_hints setting: on
max_connections setting: 100
max_worker_processes setting: 8
max_wal_senders setting: 10
max_prepared_xacts setting: 0
max_locks_per_xact setting: 64
track_commit_timestamp setting: off
Maximum data alignment: 8
Database block size: 8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072
WAL block size: 8192
Bytes per WAL segment: 16777216
Maximum length of identifiers: 64
Maximum columns in an index: 32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk: 1996
Size of a large-object chunk: 2048
Date/time type storage: 64-bit integers
Float8 argument passing: by value
Data page checksum version: 1
```

Comment: Look in the log file.

Comment: Is WAL archiving turned on ?

Answer (score 0):

The max_wal_size is Maximum size to let the WAL grow during automatic checkpoints. This is a soft limit; WAL size can exceed max_wal_size under special circumstances, such as heavy load, a failing archive_command, or a high wal_keep_size setting. If this value is specified without units, it is taken as megabytes. The default is 1 GB. Increasing this parameter can increase the amount of time needed for crash recovery. This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server command line.